# facing syntax error at or near if postgres

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I am new to POSTGRES and currently exploring how to create and execute stored procedures. I was trying a simple example with conditional constructs and got stuck with an error :(

```
create procedure learnpostgre(x integer, y integer)
language plpgsql
as $$
if x > y
then
raise 'X is greater'
end if
$$;
```

The error I am getting is 'syntax error at or near if'. I saw similar issues on SO and tried wrapping my code block under do block but faced the same error message for 'Do'. I am running my code in pgadmin4 and postgres version is 14.X

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) you need a `begin ... end` block in PL/pgSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `begin` and `end` and a few semicolons. This should work:

```
create procedure learnpostgre(x integer, y integer)
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
if x > y
then
raise 'X is greater';
end if;
end
$$
```

Comment: it worked. Thanks. I guess I am still confusing it with sql syntax.